# Как хранить в поле данные из других классов в php?

Tags: php

**Как в статическом приватном поле  products хранить все созданные продукты(Processors и Ram).Т.е что бы это поле было регистром продуктов**

```
<?php
namespace lesson2;

header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');


class User{
private $name;
private $balance;

function __construct($name,$balance){
    $this->name = $name;
    $this->balance = $balance;
}

public function getName(){
    return $this->name;
}

public function getBalance(){
    return $this->balance;
}

public function __toString(){
    return "У пользователя ".$this->getName()." сейчас на счету ".$this->getBalance()."<br/>";
}

public function giveMoney($user, $amount){
    if($amount > $this->balance){
        echo 'Недостаточно средств!'."<br/>";
    }
    else{
        $this->balance = $this->balance - $amount;
        $user->balance = $user->balance + $amount;
        echo "Пользователь ".$this->getName()." перечислил ".$amount." пользователю ".$this->getBalance()."<br/>";
    }

}

}

abstract class Product{
private $name;
private $price;
private $owner;
static private $products;

public function setOwner(User $user){
    $this->owner = $user;
}

function __construct($name, $price, $owner){
    $this->name = $name;
    $this->price = $price;
    $this->owner = $owner;
}

}

class Processor extends Product{
private $frequency;

}

class Ram extends Product{
private $type;
private $memory;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понял вопрос то речь шла об этом:

```
abstract class Product
{
    static private $products = [];
    
    public static function setProducts($product)
    {
        self::$products[] = $product;
    }
    
    public static function getProducts()
    {
        return self::$products;
    }
}

class Processor extends Product
{
    private $frequency;
}

class Ram extends Product
{
    private $type;
    private $memory;
}

Ram::setProducts('item1');
Processor::setProducts('itemProc1');
Processor::setProducts('itemProc2');

print_r(Ram::getProducts());
print_r(Processor::getProducts());
```

Результат:

```
Array
(
    [0] => item1
    [1] => itemProc1
    [2] => itemProc2
)
Array
(
    [0] => item1
    [1] => itemProc1
    [2] => itemProc2
)
```